# Is there a way to index a list matrix using a single for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, matrix

I have a problem that involves taking a square matrix in list form and finding the absolute value of the difference between the primary diagonal and the secondary diagonal. For example, given the following list:

```
test_matrix = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
```

The correct solution returns

```
15
```

My solution which works is:

```
def diagonalDifference(test_matrix):
    primary_diag = 0
    secondary_diag = 0

    for i, row in enumerate(test_matrix):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            if (i == j) and ((i + j) == len(test_matrix) - 1):
                secondary_diag += val
                primary_diag += val
            elif i == j:
                primary_diag += val
            elif (i + j) == len(test_matrix) - 1:
                print('secondary_diag:' + str(val))
                secondary_diag += val

    return abs(primary_diag - secondary_diag)
```

Which works fine but I was hoping if someone could tell me if there is a way to reproduce the solution using only one for loop. Any other improvements that can be made are also welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I, in python, iterate over multiple 2d lists at once, cleanly?](/questions/189087)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a core Python solution, let me offer a numpy-based solution that may be faster for large matrices:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(test_matrix)
np.abs((np.diag(arr) - np.diag(np.fliplr(arr))).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve the underlying problem in O(N), by simply iterating over possible row indices and using them to compute both row and column indices to index the (square) input data:

```
def diagonalDifference(test_matrix):
    diff = 0

    for i in range(len(test_matrix)):
        diff += test_matrix[i][i]
        diff -= test_matrix[i][-i-1]
    
    return abs(diff)

test_matrix = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
print(diagonalDifference(test_matrix))
```